# malloc in a while loop

Tags: c, unix, malloc

In the below code, I have put a malloc call in a while loop

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    while(1) { 
        ptr=malloc(1000);
        if (ptr == NULL) break;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Will the `while loop` run until there is space left in heap or will it continue to run forever unless it is killed since we are not writing any data in the allocated memory?
Of course there is a memory leak which is intended so that the above question can be answered.

Comment: this seems like malicious code!

Comment: @Vikdor: I dont have the environment right now, wud hav tried otherwise

Comment: You do realize that your edit COMPLETELY changes the sense of the question? What was an excellent answer to the first version becomes an horrible answer to the second, and perhaps even vice-versa. Please do not edit your questions in this way.

Comment: Sorry, but I wrote a comment after editing. Also, I edited the question at a very earl stage when there was only one response.

Answer (score 2):

After a certain iterations `malloc` will fail. Since you don't check for the return value of malloc, there's nothing to break the loop.

So it'll loop infinitely.

---

With your break, it'll eventually break out of the loop when malloc returns NULL. AS you already mentioned, there's memory leak. Typically OS will claim all the memory once the program exits. Although, it's a good practice to `free` it properly.

Comment: I imagine that even checking for the return value will not prevent this from crashing on Linux, because Linux oversubscribes memory.

Comment: I forgot to put a break. Now i have updated the code, what would happen now?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think it'll crash. Eventually malloc will run of out memory and return NULL. I don't see any issue as it's a graceful exit. Any reason why you think it'd crash?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Even if Linux oversubscribes memory, it will still eventually run out of virtual address space (though that might take a very long time on a 64-bit machine), since `malloc` is required to return pointer values different from any other existing valid pointer.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Sure, but you'll get OOM-killed before you get a chance to run out of addresses, I imagine.

Comment: @KerrekSB malloc merely reserves virtual address space. See my comment on a deleted post (which I can't see now :). OOM killer will be invoked only when the process *uses* it which is a different case. For example in the above code if there's a statement like `ptr[999]=123;` inside the loop then it'll crash due OOM-kiiler as the process *uses* it.

Comment: Yes, in the above program OOM will not be invoked because nothing is being written into the allocated memory. malloc will return NULL when it can no longer reserve memory i.e when it exceeds the user space memory.

Answer (score 0):

The process will eventually reach a limit (process limit, user limit, disk limit) and then die gracefully. It will probably be thrashing your hard disk and the rest of the system will grind to a halt for a considerable period of time.

The OS does not give a fig if you use the memory.

It will eventually recover. But why do something this stupid?

Comment: As others said, this really depends on the OS. Linux will give you as much memory as you want (and fits into your adress space), unless you start using it. At the very moment you're actually using more memory than available, your process will be OOM-killed.